# Incoming calls and alarm not showing on lock screen

Tags: android, phone-call, android-alarms, lockscreen, android-phone-call

I've created an lock screen app and when I try to unlock phone, my lock screen activity is showing but the problem is when someone calls me and at the same time if lock screen activity is showing, the incoming calls or alarm not showing.

Can anyone let me know, what's the issue?

Manifest file :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />

<activity
            android:name=".OneActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@style/noActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan">
        </activity>

<receiver android:name=".utils.ReciverUnlockScreen" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you show the LockScreen you have to check for "TelephonyManager.getCallState()" to verify if there is an active incoming/outgoing call.

Comment: Okay and then what should I need to do?

Comment: So I think I don't have understood...you said that the problem is when a call is made/received JUST WHEN you are showing/displaying the LockScreen. It's right? So you just have to manage this small case. If the problem is that you NEVER see the voicecall interface due to the fact that your LockScreen covers it, than one solution is to do the suggested check and if an active call is detected then temporarily HIDE your custom lockscreen until it ends.

Comment: Thanks @emandt this is working with phone calls but what about alarm? I need to finish my lock screen when alarm is in action. Any help?